# Dart - what might cause a stream to close or return? Is there a way to force it to stay open?

Tags: dart

I'm testing the output of a stream built from a StreamController.  Only half my results are coming back in my unit test.  It seems to be closing or returning early.

What causes a stream to close or return in Dart?  Is there a way to keep it open?

Comment: Convert stream to future list.

Comment: ah, thank you @Kahou, that solved it!